# What is the word describing renaming an event or process with a symbolic phrase or word?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in an aerospace business setting we are trying to find a title for the process to get approval for a new good or service.  We are suggesting names like: green light, take off, launch pad, etc...

What are these names called?  Is there a word for it?
They are not euphemisms because we're not referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.
It's not stenography because we're not trying to hide anything.

Usage example:
I don't like "green light" as a (word) because it's too vague.
I think a better (word) would be "take off".

I'm thinking maybe jargon is the right word for it.  It would not be industry-specific or even company-specific jargon.  I think the phrase I'm looking to identify with the word would be department specific.

Comment: Are you after another name for greenlight/takeoff/launchpad or the name for the process of coming up with one of those names?

Comment: Hi Wade, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1):

An *idiom* is a set phrase that has acquired a meaning separate from the combined meaning of the individual words. A *metaphor* is figurative language in which an analogy is implicitly given.

Answer (score 1):

Those names (symbolic words or phrases) are terms specific to the respective field and the technical term (mass noun) for them is ***terminology***, sometimes also referred to as ***nomenclature*** or ***jargon***.

ODO:

> **[terminology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/terminology)**
>   *NOUN* [mass noun]   The body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, profession, etc.
>
> ‘I realise that the army's history and terminology is an unknown jungle to many.’
>
> **[nomenclature](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nomenclature)**
>
> *NOUN* [mass noun]
>   **1.1** The body or system of names used in a particular specialist field.   ‘the students found it hard to decipher the nomenclature of
>   chemical compounds’
>
> **1.2** [*formal*] The term or terms applied to someone or something.   ‘‘customers’ was preferred to the original nomenclature ‘passengers’’
>
> **[jargon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jargon)**
>   *NOUN*   [mass noun]
>   **1** Special words or expressions used by a profession or group that are difficult for others to understand.
>
> ‘legal jargon’

Answer (score 0):

JARGON [noun].  Given the responses, it must be "jargon".  We are simply creating corporate speak for our department, jargon.